# Baffle and insulation question

Tags: insulation, baffling

I'm working on finishing my attic space (getting more electric up there, heating/cooling, walls etc.). There is a full stairwell to get into the attic space. Ceiling are 8ft tall.

This is a semi-DIY project, and I decided to take on installing the baffles. One of my questions is when I install the baffles should I install them all the way from the soffit to the ridge vent or just over the areas that will end up having insulation near them (ie soffit and where the dry wall will be)?

Right now most of the attic outside the subfloor has batt insulation. Part of the attic has that and some blown in insulation as well. My question is should I blow in a bunch more insulation before I put the walls up?

Final question, parts under my subfloor has zero insulation it (this was a fun find the was 17 years old when we got it!). Do I need to put any in there with the expectation that area will be enclosed with the finished space (walls will have insulation).

Thank you!

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour] so you know how this site works, then revise to ask _one_ question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Baffles are used to prevent insulation from blocking ventilation of the roof deck.

No insulation close to the deck, no need for baffles.

Insulation is used to wrap the living space from outside temperatures, usually the top most ceiling of heated space and the walls. If part of the sub floor is outside of the heated space, that should be insulated.

Comment: How close is "close"?

That part of the subfloor will be encapsulated in the conditioned air with a mini split(HVAC guy recommendation).  Since the minisplit is not always going to be running it seems to make sense to me to put insulation in the subfloor that currently has none.

Comment: @Jozney  Close enough to have a chance of blocking air flow.  Will depend on insulation type, ridged foam can be placed precisely, fiber can move a bit, blown in needs baffles the most.  If heating only used once in while and the rest of time no heat, then insulating sub floor might be good.  Heat rises so bottom floor heat will go up, so adds cost to heating.  Any water pipes up there, you want heat on all the time, on low at least.